# Issue with Scrapy on button click

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using Scrapy. I have an anchor tag within a form. Here is how it looks.

```
<form id="id8" method="post" action="?x=jmm9hwO6whVFYOGs283r0oqegcq8yXZcwcLUxU*NCVmxpqCK*OWQzUdI-IbQ6HlEzZltb5qJVzerKYQCL6HzihRR9N8V514r"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="id8_hf_0" id="id8_hf_0"></div><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="text" autocomplete="false"><input type="submit" name="linkFrag:beginButton" onclick=" var b=document.getElementById('id9'); if (b!=null&amp;&amp;b.onclick!=null&amp;&amp;typeof(b.onclick) != 'undefined') {  var r = b.onclick.bind(b)(); if (r != false) b.click(); } else { b.click(); };  return false;"></div>

<div id="welcomePageHeader" class="adminMainHeader"><h2><span>Welcome Page</span></h2></div>
<!-- div class="adminContentHead subsection2 bgClr2"><span wicket:id="portalName"></span></div -->
<div class="formSec bgClr1 welcomePageSec">
    <div id="acknowledgement">
        <div style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <a href="#" class="anchorButton" name="linkFrag:beginButton" id="id9" onclick="var wcall=wicketSubmitFormById('id8', '?x=jmm9hwO6whVFYOGs283r0oqegcq8yXZcwcLUxU*NCVmxpqCK*OWQzT6gI89aPkynDZsfSFy0vfCZ8uZoIAv57mMqr2tk6xTsXvag2x0Lls69vFKIQ4*fYtWt7EDYFB1mGj7vxgn8Frj5gSWKFqJKjjfDNioG2zA9SBQwdbcR*80', 'linkFrag:beginButton' ,function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$$(this)&amp;&amp;Wicket.$$('id8')}.bind(this));;; return false;"><span>Search</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="notice" class="subsection1 bgClr2">
        <span type="text" id="alertTextInput" class="containerSpacing"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am unable to click anchor tag link and proceed. Tried below options till now.

1. Proceeding to a normal link within anchor tag

   ```
   next_page_url = response.xpath('//div[@id="acknowledgement"]//a/@href').extract_first()
   if next_page_url is not None:
       next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
       yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback = self.search_court_case)
   ```
2. Sending a Form Request

   ```
   yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                   formxpath = "//*[@id=\"id8\"]",
                                   callback=self.parse1)
   ```

Can someone guide on how this issue can be resolved? Also i read many articles that Scrapy is unable to handle Javascript. If you notice in above HTML, anchor tag is calling a Javascript function which does nothing but POSTs a form with token. Is there any way to simulate that using Scrapy?

Comment: You will likely need to use selenium.  Can you post the webpage you are trying to scrap please.

Comment: @nevster Traversing from http://courts.alaska.gov/search-cases.htm to http://www.courtrecords.alaska.gov/eservices/home.page.2. On this page there is a button for Searching Records.

Comment: @nevster Can you please help me with above urls?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?